# Formula to sum up cells with delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

Is it possible to sum up cells with a slash delimiter?
What can be the formula in this case?

P.S.: I'm using jxls, so formulas like `$[SUM(A10)]` works for me as well.

```
------------------------
|January  |  100 / 40  |
------------------------
|February |  200 / 60  |
------------------------
|March    |  300 / 80  |
------------------------
|April    |  400 / 100 |
------------------------
|May      |  500 / 50  |
------------------------
|Total    | 1500 / 330 |
------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and Parse the parts:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--TRIM(LEFT(B2:B6,FIND("/",B2:B6)-1)))&" / "&SUMPRODUCT(--TRIM(MID(B2:B6,FIND("/",B2:B6)+1,999)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @scott-craner, your solution works! Unfortunately, I can't vote for it, because my reputation is too low.

Comment: You can click the check mark by the answer you used to mark that one the most correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `IMSUM` function to sum up range of cells with a slash delimiter

In `B7` enter array formula (Confirm by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>) :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IMSUM(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B6&"i"," / ","-")),"-"," / "),"i","")
```

[image]

Comment: I've never seen `IMSUM` been used before. Very clever solution +

Answer (score 0):

In **C1** enter:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(B1,FIND("/",B1)-1))+TRIM(MID(B1,FIND("/",B1)+1,99))
```

[image]

If you are interested in a column sum, then consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function zum(rng As Range) As String
    Dim z1 As Long, z2 As Long, r As Range
    z1 = 0
    z2 = 0
    For Each r In rng
        arr = Split(Replace(r.Value, " ", ""), "/")
        z1 = z1 + arr(0)
        z2 = z2 + arr(1)
    Next r

    zum = CStr(z1) & " / " & CStr(z2)
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column to the right with the formula below, and do and sum below it.

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)))
```

then can sum this column with simple sum function.